# Enable button when i have selected two values

Tags: angularjs

I have two select i want to enable my button when i have selected values in my two select, i don't know how i can do this ?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p0t4cw84/)

***My HTML:***

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select 
            ng-options="people.first for people in people_1"
            ng-model="selectedPerson1"></select>
        <select
               ng-options="people.first for people in people_2"
            ng-model="selectedPerson2"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <br/><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="platform=true">Comparer</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the `ng-disabled` directive. I have amended your jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/p0t4cw84/3/. I moved the button into the scope of the controller `FirstCtrl` and added a method on the scope that will return true or false if values are selected.

```
$scope.enableCompare = function () {
    return !($scope.selectedPerson1 && $scope.selectedPerson2);
};
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.There are lot of issue in you fiddle.I fixed it.

http://jsfiddle.net/purpz7u3/

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <fieldset >
        <select 
            ng-options="people.first for people in people_1"
            ng-model="selectedPerson1" ng-change="check()"></select>
        <select
               ng-options="people.first for people in people_2"
            ng-model="selectedPerson2" ng-change="check()"></select>
    </fieldset>
                <br/><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="checked">Comparer</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;

```
$scope.people_1 = [
    { id: 1, first: 'John' },
    { id: 2, first: 'Rocky' }
];
   $scope.people_2 = [
    { id: 1, first: 'Rambo' },
    { id: 2, first: 'Balboa'}
];
$scope.check = function(){
    if($scope.selectedPerson1 && $scope.selectedPerson2){
        $scope.checked=false;
    }
}
```

});